# Osxcross building invalid operand error

Tags: makefile, compilation, autotools, bitcoin

I'm attempting to build [Slimminer](https://github.com/JonnyLatte/slimminer) which is based on [cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer) with osxcross on Linux. I configured it with:

```
CC=o64-clang CXX=o64-clang++ ./configure ---host=x86_64-apple-darwin10.11
```

which configures it with no errors. I am attempting to make it with:

```
make CC=o64-clang CXX=o64-clang++
```

I receive many errors while making it all saying either:

```
error: invalid operand for instruction
   or
while in macro instantiation
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to my ignorance. I did not read the build instructions fully. I did not run

```
./nomacro.pl
```

which solved the problem.